# Cannot open database "DBName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MachineName\User'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a web application but when trying to connect the DB I am getting this error

Cannot open database "DBName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MachineName\User'.

I also tried adding that this user manually but it give error that this login already exist with different username..but it not shows in DB permission list.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4e6cky(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming this is MS-Sql. Try to delete the existing user from the database and then reassociate the login with the database again. You will then not get the error that the user already exists. Will need further details if this doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [sp_change_users_login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) with the AUTO_FIX option.

```
sp_change_users_login @Action=AUTO_FIX, @UserNamePattern='MachineName\User'
```